# Is it possible to make laptop as a server to host application globally on wireless network (not LAN )?

Tags: r, web-applications, server, shiny, web-hosting

I have created one application on R Shiny and want it to publish globally so that any user can have access to it.

I have already explored free shiny server (i.e shinyapps.io) to host it but my application contains SQLite at the back-end to collect responses from users and shiny doesn't allow to write to the database and doesn't have this functionality however i tried this by publishing on shiny server but was unable to write responses to database.

So is it possible to make own laptop as server to host application that can accessible globally to the user on wireless network,it is possible on LAN(not current requirement) and i am not aware to how to do the same using wireless network or is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not use `ec2`, `googlecloud` or `azure` to get a free `vm` for a year and host on that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt reply :)
Let me explore this.